# on() does not work correctly

Tags: jquery

I need to execute the following script on newly added element

```
$(".select").selectmenu();
```

The newly added element is:

```
<div class="Div11" >
  <label>Choisir Une Colonne</label>
  <select  class="select">
    <option value="Sum">Somme</option>
    <option value="Max">Max</option>
    <option value="Avarage">Moyenne</option>
    <option value="Min">Min</option>
  </select>

  <label>Choisir Une Colonne</label>
  <select  class="select">
    <option value="Col1">Col1</option>
    <option value="Col2">Col2</option>
    <option value="Col3">Col3</option>
    <option value="Col4">Col4</option>      
  </select>
</div>
```

I wrote the following script:

```
$(document).on('change ready', 'select', function() {
  alert('ok');
  $(".select").selectmenu();
});
```

However, this doesn't work. What's going wrong with this script?

Comment: Neither the `change` nor the `ready` event fire when an `option` is appended to a `select` element. If you want that behaviour you'll need to use a MutationObserver. Alternatively, trigger the event yourself when you append the new option. The latter is by far the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, giving an element a class of its own name is redundant. The full selector would be `div.Div11` and `select.select`. Maybe choose a class name that's a little more descriptive.

Second, I don't think the document ever fires a change event (There are DOM mutation events https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events and observers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver, but I'm not sure those are considered best practices). So you're only binding to the selects that already exist when the page loads. When you dynamically add code, you have to add the event listener after it exists in the DOM.

I'm not sure how you're adding your html, but you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  $('your html').appendTo(document).find('select').selectmenu();
});
```

EDIT: Although, if you have more than one select you may have to call `.selectmenu()` on each one.

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
  $('your html').appendTo(document).find('select').each(function() {
    $(this).selectmenu();
});
```

Comment: this is how i'm adding my html  $("#Div1Plus").click(function(event){
            $("#Div11").children(':first').clone().appendTo(".Div1");
            $(".select").selectmenu();

        });

Comment: ($(".select").selectmenu();) does duplicate the select in the page!!

Comment: Something similar should still work.  `$("#Div1Plus").click(function(event){ $("#Div11").children(':first').clone().appendTo(".Div1")**.find**(".select").selectmenu(); });`

Comment: i found where come the problem , the selectMenu called in document.ready and applied to the first div wich div will be cloned caused the problem. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `select` element is you add later,not exist when the page on load.

Suppose `<div class="Div11"></div>` is fixed(means it exist when the page on load),you can change to below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".Div11").on("change","select",function(event){
      alert("ok");
      $(this).selectmenu();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of event here.

Once you set the html contents you need to call `$(".select").selectmenu();`

If you are setting the html content inside the success handler of `$.ajax()` you need to call `$(".select").selectmenu();` there.

If you don't have control over this you need to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check when a DOM node is added.

Comment: it's very nice idea . I don't add this element via ajax. but the idea behind worked for me :)